# How to export dimension name and its universe name to CSV or Excel?

Tags: export, business-objects

I'm new with this, but I'm in a healthcare company and I need to know if there are options in SAP BO for export sap dimension name and its universe name to csv or Excel.

I need a dataset with a column for dimension name and other for universe name.

Thanks.

Comment: There are no options as you describe built into the core of SAP BusinessObjects. Check out the free tools from [biclever](http://biclever.com/). They might have what you need.